# How do I get rows from a table without duplicates when I use the ORDER by?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm creating a journal database. My table structure has a column called `journals` which has a value for every article inserted. Now I want to select from the table and order by `date_added` but to skip selecting any two articles from the same journal.

Comment: please show some sample data and expected result

Comment: Did you try anything add that as well

Comment: The ORDER BY has nothing to do with it. If a journal has several articles, which one do you want to return?

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for

```
select J1.journal, J1.article, J2.DatePublished
from
journals J1
inner join 
(
    select journal, max(publishdate) as DatePublished -- shows only the most recent article 
    from journals
    group by journal 
    order by DatePublished desc -- date ordered descending for s&g
) J2
  on J2.journal = J1.journal
  and J2.DatePublished = J1.publishdate
```